# rails - favicon showing up on firefox, but not on chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

```
= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
```

Many answers say to put it in either the assert folder or the public folder, so I have the favicon icon in both `app/assets/images` and `public/images`. When I test my app locally in chrome, the favicon does not show up, but when I test it on firefox developer edition, the favicon shows.

I have cleared both the history and cache for both browser.

I've deployed the app on heroku, and it also only shows on firefox but not chrome.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First of all, use the developer tools (network panel) to see if Chrome actually requests it, and what the server’s response is – everything ok there? Does the server deliver it using an appropriate mime type in the `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the favicon.ico is saved in Cache, try to clean your chrome's Cache again.

If that doesn't help. Try to do this.

**Delete all your data**
In the top-right corner of Chrome, click the Chrome menu Chrome Menu.
Select More tools > Clear browsing data.
In the dialog that appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. Select beginning of time to delete everything.
Click Clear browsing data.

That helped me.